# File Source Connection Expression in SSIS for file in Bulk Insert Task Editor

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ssis

Is there a way to do a expression for the Source Connection. I have entered in an expression under source connection and it is not working? Or could it be done in a script task? I want to have the folder part of the expression as a variable.I have Visual Studio 2008. I am getting the error.

```
Error at InsertIntoClientStaging: The connection "C:\Temp\Attributes.bin" is not found. 
This error is thrown by Connections collection when the specific connection element is not found.
```

In the XML I have this prpoerty.

```
BulkInsertTask:SourceConnectionName="C:\Temp\Attributes.bin"
```

It seems if this thinks it is it's name and not it's path.

Comment: Please be more specific about what "it is not working" means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - Your source connection would point to a connection manager and then you would amend the "connection managers connection" via an expression e.g. different server name depending on whether you are in live or dev.

I personally try and avoid script tasks where possible for the simple reason that they are harder for the next developer to understand what is going on - without having to delve into the script.

Comment: Thanks for that.This leads to my next question which is when doing the script task I do not have a selection of the file connection manger in the script read and write variables. How to I edit the file connection manager?

Comment: Why are you using a script task?

Comment: Because the source connection that I am using an expression to create in the bulk insert is not working. I create the it using an expression. The file exists and it wont work. I was previously using a file connection manager and now I have to create the source file or file connection manger based on a variable. Unfortunately I do not have the exact wording of the problem in front of me as I am not at work now.

Comment: It basically creates the file exactly and I can see what it creates but then it fails.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my problem is to click on the File Connection and then select properties. Then click on the Expression's three dots. Then enter my expression for the connection string there for the file connection. Yes this is easy. Before hand I was not aware of the expression for the File Connection and was simply double clicking on the file connection and not getting the ability to enter an expression there. I was thus entering the expression in the source connection of the bulk insert.

Comment: Which is the answer I provided :-)